# E: Unable to locate package python-pygraphviz E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate

Tags: python, ns-3

I wanted to use ns3 for which some prerequisites have to be met in Ubuntu. (https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation)
First of all I cannot use `apt-get install python-pygraphviz python-kiwi python-pygoocanvas libgoocanvas-dev ipython` command as it shows :E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

When I write the same command as root user,`sudo apt-get install gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0 python-gi python-gi-cairo python-pygraphviz python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-pygraphviz gir1.2-gtk-3.0 ipython ipython3` 
The command line interface shows,
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ipython is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package python-pygraphviz
E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate
What should I do ? Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you install `ipython`?

Comment: @thenewjames Yes by using the command  sudo apt install -y python3-pip
Even after that , I get the same error

Comment: Did you try searching for the error code? [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298398/e-package-ipython-has-no-installation-candidate-while-trying-to-install-tor) took me 30 seconds and it might solve your issue

Comment: try `sudo apt install python3-pygraphviz`. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```sh
# Install pip
sudo apt install -y python3-pip

# Install ipython
pip3 install ipython
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298398/e-package-ipython-has-no-installation-candidate-while-trying-to-install-tor

Comment: Thanks.. I tried doing all of them but it didn't work...I guess it isn't compatible with Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.When I tried installing ns3 and its package in Ubuntu 16.0 LTS everything went smoothly without any error..

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command:

sudo apt install ipython

then do the follwing:

sudo apt install python3-pygraphviz

or

sudo apt-get install python3-pygraphviz